# Is there a WannaCry patch for Windows 8 Embedded?

Tags: windows-embedded-8, wannacrypt

MS17-010 doesn't appear to support Windows 8 Embedded.  The patch that came out with Windows Updates in March supports Windows 8.1. There are links to manually downloading the patch KB4012598 for Windows 8 (Doesn't mention embedded) but they don't install.  Was 8 embedded left out?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a WannaCry patch for Windows 8 Embedded?

It was released back on March 13: **KB4012217**

> - March, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Embedded 8 Standard for x64-based Systems (KB4012217)
> - March, 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows Embedded 8 Standard for x64-based Systems (KB4012214)
> - March, 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows Embedded 8 Standard (KB4012214)
> - March, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Embedded 8 Standard (KB4012217)

[Patches That Fix the Vulnerability For MS17-010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sudheesn/2017/05/17/patches-that-fix-the-vulnerability-for-ms17-010/)

Comment: I don't see the point of linking to the patch on: [Microsoft Catalog Update](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com) website but would if that's requested.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information.  I have Windows Update set to Auto, but nothing was installed during the month of March other than a Visual C++ update. I do not see KB4012217 installed. Strange.  I will see if I can find this patch on MS Web site as a download and see if I can get it installed. Not sure why it wasn't included in the auto updates.  Anyway, thank you again for this article link as it's been very hard to find anything about this patch for Embedded 8.  Cheers!

Comment: I was able to find and download this update from Microsoft. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Well, this patch doesn't install on my WE8 system either. I wonder if there is a newer Security Monthly Quality Rollup that included these updates that was installed prior to March? Anyway, still trying to determine if this patch has been applied to my WE8 system or not.  Cheers.

Comment: @user729247 - *I wonder if there is a newer Security Monthly Quality Rollup that included these updates that was installed prior to March?* - Nope.  *Anyway, still trying to determine if this patch has been applied to my WE8 system or not. Cheers.* - There are only two possible patches KB4012217 or KB4012214 that patch this vulnerability.  You really should determine the reason KB4012214 is not being installed though.

Comment: Be sure you have Windows 8 Embedded not Windows 8.1 Industry Pro because it does not appear that KB4012214 is applicable to Windows 8.1 Industry Pro

Comment: @Ramhound **Windows 8 Embedded** family has 3 products: **Standard**, **Industry** & **Pro**. Though I have a tablet that says it's Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro, probably because the Industry version has all the Pro's features + some extras (?!?).

Comment: I was able to find and download KB4012214. KB4012214 did install on my WE8 systems. :)   KB4012217 for some reason would not install.  Thank you for all your suggestions/helps.

Comment: @user729247 That is because `KB4012217` is for **Windows 8 Embedded** only not Windows 8.1 Embedded.  Your question mentions you are running Windows 8 Embedded.